# Keeping a Clean Home Folder

Tags: nautilus

I installed n (node.js version manager) recently, as well as npm, and node.js. I can't tell which program is to blame, but there are tmp, local, share,  and bin folders in my home folder as well as a README and LICENSE AGREEMENT.

This doesn't strike me as a clean home folder anymore. Am I being overly picky? Or is there something I can do to keep that folder clean?

Here's 3 directories deep on my home folder:

```
.
├── bin
├── costa
├── Desktop
├── Documents
├── Downloads
│   ├── photoshop
│   └── temp node backup
├── include
│   └── node
│       ├── openssl
│       └── uv-private
├── Ingenuity Boom
│   └── ingenuityboom.com
 │       ├── node_modules
│       ├── public
│       ├── routes
│       └── views
├── lib
│   ├── dtrace
│   └── node_modules
│       └── npm
├── Music
│   └── xadjis
│       ├── cd1
│       ├── cd2
│       └── cd3
├── Node.js in Action
│   └── 8th chapter
│       ├── newApp
│       └── photos
├── Pictures
│   ├── dad
│   ├── memories
│   ├── private
│   └── Webcam
├── Public
├── share
│   ├── man
│   │   └── man1
│   └── systemtap
│       └── tapset
├── Templates
├── tmp
│   └── npm-13722
│       └── 1387898121130-0.8321310367900878
└── Videos
```

Comment: How did you install all that stuff?

Comment: apt-get for npm, then npm install -g n, then n to install the stable and latest versions of node.js

Answer (score 1):

When programs "install" (here install is a bit epic) stuff in the home directory is because they understood that you were in your current project directory. They do not install in the sense that all users can use the stuff but in the sense that "this is my project, keep all this stuff together". Some programs include removal methods using npm as example:

```
npm uninstall module_name
```

and done. If you use -g or global you must use `-g` too. For other tools they include their own removal method or you just can remove manually the directories.

Comment: Okay, so here we go. I've got npm uninstall working great, and I uninstalled and reinstalled n locally and globally, so I saw that in action. I'm having trouble with n (https://github.com/visionmedia/n) I try removing the node versions I have installed, but they're not being removed with the recommended command (sudo n rm 0.10.24). If I start node, it starts fine, but if I delete the bin folder from my home folder I get this error: bash: /home/costa/bin/node: No such file or directory.